# Forst steps to make a project visible

Tags: seo, google, advertising, website-promotion

Recently I launched some web project for musicians. Considering that:

- It is really optimized for search engines. Dynamic pages, sitemap, etc. - are up and running.
- It is indexed by Google. Google Webmaster account is adjusted. Google Analytics also
- It had some advertising already, but with minor result.

What it the best way to promote it for free?

I have read several "step-by-step" tutorials, but almost all of them say "Make SEO and wait".

**Considering a kind of this project, what activities may you suggest?**

**What did work with your own projects?**

Please shed some light on this problem for a youngster like me. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

You already did the important steps and answered your question with:

> almost all of them say "Make SEO and wait".

There is a few other ideas which may or may not work for you. Try out a Facebook Page, Twitter, and Social Networking. That usually gets people involved some more within your site and the activities of the site when you post on the social networks.

I, personally, build up a big article on my blog and pay $10 to $50 on my Facebook Page to advertise that Article to people, which gains more site views and visitors according to Google Analytics.

My Advertising method does hurt my bank account at times, but it does show some small progress with the overall returning visitors which Social Networking.